# How can I manually merge out-of-order data into a sequential format in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: database, merge, merge-conflict-resolution, apache-iotdb, iotdb

Are there any way to trigger the merging of out-of-order data into sequential data besides restarting Apache IoTDB? I think flush can only flush data and write it to disk, but it cannot let out-of-order data be written into sequential data. I know that the out-of-order data will be checked regularly by IoTDB system.

Aside from start merging at regular intervals, is there a way to start the merging process manually and how can I set this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `merge` to manually trigger the process -- merges the data in the specified storage group + deletes the merged data from the disk

1. Log in to IoTDB command-line iterface
2. `SET STORAGE GROUP root.sg1` sets storage groups to merge (in this example root.sg1 is the storage group to merge)
3. start the merging process `merge root.sg1`
4. `show merge status` to check the status.

Ps. manually triggering the merging process can be resource-intensive -- carefully consider the impact on system performance before doing so

Answer (score 0):

Currently Apache IoTDB cannot execute data merging manually, but you can adjust parameters to accelerate the default data merging frequency.

You can set these two parameters: `compaction_submission_interval_in_ms` and `compaction_schedule_interval_in_ms` from **60000** to smaller numbers to achieve this.